# How to mock block scope variables with Jest?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a method that has a const variable declared. What is the practice when testing piece of code that uses block scope variables? I am using Jest. I haven't had many situation like this one, so in some cases I would change the variable scope in order to access it in tests, only because I couldn't find a way to do it properly. I am aware that it shouldn't be done this way.

Here is my example. I need to cover for loop.

```
downloadAttachment(attachment: Attachment) {
        const byteCharacters = window.atob(attachment.attachment);
        const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
        saveAs(blob, 'attachment');
    }
```

Comment: mock the window.atob to return what you want, and leave the const variables alone :)

Comment: Why would you mock `atob` @MaciejWojcik? It's a pure function you don't own, you can control exactly what it returns with what you pass as `attachment`. A more likely candidates for a test double would surely be `saveAs`, so the rest can be treated as implementation detail.

Comment: ah yes, absolutelty - somehow I missed the input arguments

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments, guys.
Somehow I missed the fact that my mock was just an object with empty strings, which is why the for loop was not covered.

I don't think this question should've gotten -1 reputation, I'm very well aware that I should not change scope variables just for test's sake.

In case anyone will need the solution:

```
it('should downloadAttachment', () => {
        const attachment = {
            id: '2',
            attachment:
                '/9j/4AA....igD/9k=',
            creationDate: '2016-07-29 07:51:29'
        };
        const spy = jest.spyOn(component, 'downloadAttachment');
        component.downloadAttachment(attachment);
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Since attachment is an image, I had to find the corresponding image data representation.

Comment: It seems you want to test `downloadAttachment` method and why did you spy on it? What code branch did you test?